Grant Shortcuts permission to save file to folder
I have a Shortcut which processes images as a Quick Action. The Shortcuts ends with:

Set name of [Converted File] to [Name.heic]
Save [Renamed Item] to [Specific Folder] (Overwrite If File Exists)

This has worked fine for years. In Sequoia now, it's popping up:
[Privacy]

Allow "My Shortcut" to access your "Specific Folder" folder?

[Cancel] [OK]

Pressing OK, a notification pops up:

You don't have permission.
The file couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it.

Clicking on that jumps to the Save step in the Shortcut and repeats the same message there.
I've tried giving full disk permissions to Shortcuts.app, and Allow Deleting Without Confirmation in the Shortcuts.app advanced settings, but that changes nothing.
What did Sequoia change and how to make it work again?

FWIW, letting it ask for a folder instead of pre-selecting one works. But I want to hardcode it to a specific folder.

That seems to be the intended behavior. The release notes for Sequoia mention that some potential vulnerabilities in Shortcuts were fixed, but don't say how. I think direct user interaction is now required to access folders protected by TCC.

I'm having the same issue for a shortcut that reads files from my Desktop folder.

Mmm, great, so they've neutered a pretty useful/important part of Shortcuts with no alternative? I'm all for security, but that basically makes certain actions/options of Shortcuts unusable.

I've been experiencing exactly this problem, and it's infuriating.
This change appears to break every file access action in Shortcuts, so I don't think it can be deliberate. I won't speculate on the cause, but I expect this will be fixed in a future release.
I thought it was fixed in 15.0.1 because immediately after updating my shortcuts began to work as expected. However, they failed again the next day, and nothing I could do would make the granted permissions 'stick'.
I now believe that the bug emerges after my laptop has slept and that restarting clears it, restoring normal function to Shortcuts.
My suggestion is therefore to update to the latest OS version and restart your machine each day. Good luck.

Yes, I’ve seen the same thing. What I noticed is that Time Machine backups fail when the screen gets locked; upon next login there’s an error notification to that effect pointing out some permission problem. There seems to be a real issue with weird new hard lockdowns or something upon locking/sleeping.

For me, the Seqouia 15.0.1 (24A348) update resolves this - no more prompts, and Shortcuts correctly continue.

Looks like it, yes. It has a new permission popup now, which allows "Allow always", wich seems to work.
